# typeahead directive doesn't bubble up the event to the external global javascript function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-typeahead

I am very new to AngularJS Directives and trying to figure out how can i customize the angularjs directive typeahead into a directive that can be customized and extended with more functionality.

Use case: Want to be able to have a self-contained directive which we can customize so that we can pass url of the remote data source, and key and description of the returned dataset  item and pass a callback method upon selection.

I wrapped the typeahead directive in a directive and passed some customization. I have a plunker demonstrating the what I have so far, but how do i pass the data element name so that is custom.

```
<div ng-controller="quickProfileController">
    <div class="container">
    <div lookup ng-model="model1" prompt="Search for a Firm or a Fund" show-image="true" action="onSelect(model);"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" ng-show="true">
    <div lookup ng-model="model2" prompt="Search" show-image="false" action="externalCall(model);"></div>
</div>
<div>
    Total Items: {{selectionHistory.length}}
</div>
</div>
```

Module:lookupModule.js

I have a directive called: lookup (lookupDirective.js, lookupController.js, lookup.html, profileService.js)

parent controller is: quickProfileController.js

Here is a link to my working code: http://plnkr.co/edit/DAaVVY

I have spent two days trying to make this work but no luck. Any thoughts!!

Comment: You can start by correcting the typo in the declaration of ng-controller="quickProfileController" and the call to the onSelect method starts working at least.

Comment: That helped. thanks a lot. (Kicking myself right now..)

Comment: is it possible to call external javascript function? rather than function being part of another angular controller

Comment: It should work. It's i.e. no problem to use a jquery plugin in a controller or in a directive's link function.

Comment: It doesn't seem to call the external javascript function if I just add it via adding the java script function directly on the page. Can you see if the call I have in the updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/DAaVVY?p=preview with externalCall and tell me what I am doing wrong please. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but I can't find the external call.

Comment: Its in the index.html - <div lookup ng-model="model2" prompt="Search" show-image="false" action="externalCall(model);"></div>

Comment: Vanguard funds eh? Sounds interesting. As some possible options, you can pass in the controller scope - good blog here - http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/07/dont-fear-directives-in-angular-js/ and about 1/3 way down the angular docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive. You could also use the events angular provides - good blog on this here - http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/ . I have found the events route very reliable, though obviously you need to be more careful about structure as they can be a bit harder to track.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the link to the right plunker cause I still don't see the externalCall in the index.html file.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/DAaVVY. Please check again. Thanks!